# How to use progressing bar while scanning image through scanner in C# application

Tags: c#, wia

In my C# application I am using scanner through WIA, here my requirement is scanner should scan a set of images around 1 to 50 images, I have added a text box in my application to enter how many images to scan.

My application has to take the number from the text box, and scanner should scan that many times. My problem is this scanning part is working very well, and while scanning progress bar is showing only for scanning first image, and it is not showing while scanning remaining images.

this is the code I am using:

```
namespace Scnr2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog FBD = new SaveFileDialog();

            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    ScannerService sr = new ScannerService();
                    ImageFile image = sr.Scan();


                     image.SaveFile(FBD.FileName + ".jpg");

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ScannerService
    {
        public ImageFile Scan()
        {
            ImageFile image;

            WIA.CommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
            DeviceManager dm = new DeviceManagerClass();

            Device scannerDevice = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, false, false);

            Item scannerItem;

            if (scannerDevice == null)
                MessageBox.Show("No");
            if (scannerDevice != null)
            {
                scannerItem = scannerDevice.Items[1];

                image = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(
                    WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
                    WIA.WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
                    WIA.WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality,
                    WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG,
                    false,
                    true,
                    false);

                return image;


            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: show code you tried to show progress bar.

Comment: you may need to reset progressbar value for each scan.

Comment: I didn't used any progress bar in my Form, I got the above code from online but I am getting a progressing bar in separate window while running, can you help me how to change that progressing bar